# Cannot undo downvote

Tags: bug, status-norepro, votes

I had downvoted [an answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/814/can-a-second-chernobyl-happen-at-the-nuclear-reactors-damaged-by-the-tsunami-in/843#843) which was relating factually wrong information.

In the meantime the posting has been edited to reflect this and now I want to remove my downvote but I can’t. Every time I try to either remove my downvote or convert it into an upvote the system pops up a dialog saying “An error has occurred – please retry your request.”

**EDIT** In the meantime I was able to undo my vote. However, the original problem was reproducible over a time period so I’m not sure that the issue was just a temporary glitch.

Comment: I gave the answer one of my votes from you. :)

Comment: Belongs on MSO. Do You want me to migrate it?

Comment: @Borror0 Yes, please do.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a deployment artifact? Did you try clearing browser cache? We're optimizing how we deliver javascript so there have been lots of changes recently to that.

As long as a post has been *edited* you are free to change your vote.

If the post has not been edited, you have a 5 minute grace period to change your vote (a limited # of times even within that 5 minute window), after that, the vote is locked in as the `<div>` explains.

Comment: I did clear it, it was not the cache. Tried on ie8, chrome latest and ff4

Comment: @Sklivvz So you had the same problem? As I’ve said in the edit, the problem went away for me after a few hours so a deployment artifact could explain this.

Comment: @Konrad Yes - It also went away after a few hours. So not a deployment artifact - more probably a bad code dump!?

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem all over StackExchange, not just `Skeptics`, which is the reason why It belongs to pure `meta`.

I once had a similar situation, and found an existing thread [on pure meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49206/156431) where I wrote an answer - maybe the thread fits to you, maybe not.

(In the first moment I wrote, that I opened such a thread, but that was wrong).

Comment: The meta thread is unrelated – in my case the answer *was* edited so this is a bug.

Comment: Unrelated, ok, but a generic meta question, probably, though?

Comment: Hmm, I’m unsure. I’ll let a moderator decide. Either way it will be found since the `bug` tag is monitored by the nice SE people. ;-)